# Reconfigure postgres with kubectl apply command

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm trying to change the settings of my postgres database inside my local minikube cluster. I mistakenly deployed a database without specifying the postgres user, password and database.

**The problem**: When I add the new env variables and use `kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yml`, postgres does not create the user, password or database that specified by the environment variables.

This is the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres
          env:
            - name: PGUSER
              value: admin
            - name: PGPASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: PGDATABSE
              value: testdb
```

How can I change the settings of postgres when I apply the deployment file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share pod's logs?

```
kubectl logs <pod_name>
```

Postgres is using init script with defined variable names:

```
POSTGRES_USER
POSTGRES_PASSWORD
POSTGRES_DB
```

Try this one out

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:9.6
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: admin
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: testdb
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: pg-data
      volumes:
        - name: pg-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: I found that the problem is the volume that postgres creates. The container is newly created every time, but the volume that also containers the postgres settings is not. So had to remove the volume to reconfigure postgres